# NoClassDefFound basegameutils

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, noclassdeffounderror

My android app crashes on start. I'm using unity and am making a google-play-services plugin for it.

Right now i just want a simple login to work.

This is my code:

```
package com.company.appname;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.GameHelperListener;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class Main extends UnityPlayerActivity
{
    GameHelper mHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // create game helper with all APIs (Games, Plus, AppState):
        System.out.println("creating gamehelper");
        mHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);

        GameHelperListener listener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSignInSucceeded() {
                // handle sign-in success
                System.out.println("signed in!!");
            }
            @Override
            public void onSignInFailed() {
                // handle sign-in failure (e.g. show Sign In button)
                System.out.println("sign in failed...");
            }

        };
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("setting up gamehelper");
        mHelper.setup(listener);
        System.out.println("gamehelper set up");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        System.out.println("starting gamehelper");
        mHelper.onStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        System.out.println("stopping gamehelper");
        mHelper.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
        System.out.println("gamehelper activity result");
        mHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }

    static public void Test()
    {
        System.out.println("test worked!!!");
    }
}
```

This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.ChocolatePinecone.PrincessRescueRun" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask"  android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
             android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>       
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"/>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

The building order of my plugin is:

- gen
- src
- Android Private Libraries
- Android Dependencies
- classes.jar
- basegameutils.jar

The error i get:

```
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813): Process: com.company.appname, PID: 12813
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813): Unity version     : 4.3.4f1
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813): Device model      : samsung GT-I9505
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813): Device fingerprint: samsung/jfltexx/jflte:4.4.2/KOT49H/I9505XXUGNF1:user/release-keys
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.example.games.basegameutils.R$string
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelperUtils.<clinit>(GameHelperUtils.java:33)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.onConnectionFailed(GameHelper.java:791)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.fg.a(Unknown Source)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.ei(Unknown Source)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.d(Unknown Source)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b$4.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.fg.a(Unknown Source)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$h.b(Unknown Source)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$h.a(Unknown Source)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$b.eN(Unknown Source)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ff$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-21 22:18:21.209: E/AndroidRuntime(12813):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Things i've tried:

- Cleaning the project
- Playing around with build order
- Checking if the basegameutils class is present in apk (It is present)

I have no idea what the problem may be...

Hopefully you guys can give me some pointers.

Comment: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.example.games.basegameutils.R$string**

Comment: Did you import BaseGameUtils as a library? See the instructions at https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/README.md.

Comment: I did, although not in that particular way. I added both the google play services and the basegameutils library via Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External Jars.

I have also tried adding basegameutils the other way via Properties -> Android -> Add Library, but the error still remains.

Comment: Why someone down voted?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! 
It seemed the R.java of basegameutils was not present in the apk file.

I opened the basegameutils project in eclipse, switched the building order of src and gen and built the project.